# What are the best practices for HttpClient .NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, singleton, httpclient

What are the best practices for creating a web api client with a HttpClient .NET, and use it as parent class? with the "post, get, put, delete" methods, config of HttpClient and handle exceptions..

For example:

```
public class ProductClient : BaseHttpClient
{
    public IList<TeamHeader> RetrieveAllProducts()
    {
        return BaseHttpClient.Get<IList<Product>>("WebApi/Product/GetProducts");
    }
}
```

Or is recomendable a singleton class of HttpClient?

Comment: I have used singleton implementation for httpclient as my application has very high frequency of httpclient usage. And in this case it is not the best way to use new httpclient instance every time we use it. If you don't use it quite often in your application you simply have new instance every time you access it. refer to this link http://byterot.blogspot.sg/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks!, have you a example of singleton implementation for HttpClient?